# Get column with two two rows having specific values

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
| a    | 1    |
| a    | 2    |
| a    | 3    |
| b    | 1    |
| b    | 3    |
| c    | 1    |
| c    | 2    |
```

I need to find the value of `col1` where two rows with the same `col1` value exist that has a col2 value of 1 and 2

results would be:

```
| col1 |
|------|
| a    |
| c    |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the rows with the `col2` values you want, then group by `col1` and only take the groups with `count = 2`

```
select  col1
from    yourTable
where   col2 in (1, 2)
group by col1
having  count(distinct col2) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be

```
select col1
from your_table
group by col1
having sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when col2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```